# How can I handle MySQL polygon overlap queries?

Tags: mysql, database

For example, I have a table of users. Users each are a "square" (or circle) on a map.

I want to find users that **overlap** another square on a map.  Is this currently supported in MySQL 5.6? (What about development versions of MySQL?)

Please note that I'm not looking for "find users with a point inside this square".  I'm looking for "find users whose square overlaps this square (not necessarily contain; as long as both squares touch - it's fine)".

It would really help if someone could provide an example of INSERTING records and then QUERYING them using ST_INTERSECT polygons.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-spatial-data.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c32b7/1)
[image: Polygon demonstration]

**Create table with polygon column**

Please note, that to use spatial indexes, you can not use InnoDB.
You can use the geometry without spatial indexes, but performance degrades as usual.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spatial` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `poly` geometry NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  SPATIAL INDEX `poly` (`poly`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Get 3 squares and a triangle inserted**

```
INSERT INTO `spatial` (`poly`) VALUES (GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0))',0));
INSERT INTO `spatial` (`poly`) VALUES (GeomFromText('POLYGON((10 50,50 50,50 10,10 10,10 50))',0));
INSERT INTO `spatial` (`poly`) VALUES (GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 15,5 15,5 11,1 11,1 15))',0));
INSERT INTO `spatial` (`poly`) VALUES (GeomFromText('POLYGON((11 5,15 5,15 1,11 5))',0));
```

**Select everything that intersects small square in lower left corner**
(purple square #1)

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(`poly`,
            GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 0,2 0,2 2,0 2,0 0))', 0 )
        )
;
```

**Select everything that intersects triangle ranging from lower left to lower right corners to upper right corner)**
(squares #1 and #2 and triange #4.)

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(`poly`,
            GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 0,50 50,50 0,0 0))', 0 )
        )
;
```

**Selects everything in square that is outside of our image**
(nothing)

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(`poly`,
            GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((100 100,200 100,200 200,100 200,100 100))', 0 )
        )
;
```

*Edit #1:*

I reread the question and I think you have the spatial relations a little confused. If what you want is find everything that fits wholy inside a square (polygon), then you need to use Contains/ST_Contains. Please see [spatial functions in MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions.html) to find out which function does the job for you.
Please note the following difference between ST/MBR functions:

**Selects everything that is completely inside a square (#0 from below)**
(squares #1, #2, triangle #4)

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        Contains(
          GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 0,20 0,20 20,0 20,0 0))', 0 ),
          `poly`
        )
;
```

**Selects everything that is completely inside a square (#0 from below) and shares no edges**
(square #2, triangle #4)

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Contains(
          GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 0,20 0,20 20,0 20,0 0))', 0 ),
          `poly`
        )
;
```

*Edit #2:*

Very nice addition from @StephanB ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/455a7/1/4))

> To list all intersections join the table onto itself and filter away
>   the reverse intersection

**Select any overlapping objects**

```
SELECT s1.id,AsText(s1.poly), s2.id, AsText(s2.poly)
FROM  `spatial` s1, `spatial` s2
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(s1.poly, s2.poly)
    AND s1.id < s2.id
;
```

(just note, that you should remove the `AND s1.id < s2.id` if you are working with `CONTAINS`, as `CONTAINS(a,b) <> CONTAINS(b,a)` while `Intersects(a,b) = Intersects(b,a)`)

In the following picture (non-exhaustive list):

- ## 2 intersects #6.
- ## 6 intersects #2
- ## 0 intersects #1, #2, #3, #4, #5
- ## 1 intersects #0, #5
- ## 0 contains #1, #3, #4 and #5 (#1, #3, #4 and #5 are within #0)
- ## 1 contains #5 (#5 is within #1)
- ## 0 st_contains #3, #4 and #5
- ## 1 st_contains #5

[image: Spatial relations]

*Edit #3: Searching by distance/Working in (with) circles*

MySQL does not directly support circle as a geometry, but you can use spatial function `Buffer(geometry,distance)` to work around it. What `Buffer()` does, is creating a buffer of said distance around geometry. If you start with geometry point, the buffer is indeed a circle.

You can see what buffer actually does by calling just:

```
SELECT ASTEXT(BUFFER(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(5 5)'),3))
```

(result is quite long, so i won't post it here) It actually creates polygon which represents the buffer - in this case (and my MariaDB) the result is 126 point polygon, which aproximates a circle. With such a polygon you can work as you would work with any other polygon. So there should be no performance penalty.

So if you want to **select all polygons which fall into a circle** you can rinse and repeat previous example
(this will find just the square #3)

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Contains(
          Buffer(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(6 15)'), 10),
          `poly`
        )
;
```

**Select all polygons which intersect with a circle**

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(
          Buffer(GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(6 15)'), 10),
          `poly`
        )
;
```

When working with shapes different from rectangles, you should use the `ST_*` functions. Functions without `ST_` use a bounding rectangle. So the previous example selects the triangle #4 even though it is not in the circle.

As `Buffer()` creates quite big polygons, there will definitely be some performance penalty over using the `ST_Distance()` method. Unfortunately I can not quantify it. You will have to do some benchmarking.

[image: Adding circle to first example]

Another way of finding objects by distance is using the `ST_Distance()` function.

**Select all elements from the table and compute their distance from point POINT(6 15)**

```
SELECT id, AsText(`poly`), 
    ST_Distance(poly, GeomFromText('POINT(6 15)')) 
    FROM `spatial`
;
```

You can use `ST_Distance` in `WHERE` clause as well.

**Select all elements whose distance from POINT(0 0) is less or equal than 10** (selects #1, #2 and #3)

```
SELECT id, AsText(`poly`), 
    ST_Distance(poly, GeomFromText('POINT(6 15)')) 
    FROM `spatial`
    WHERE ST_Distance(poly, GeomFromText('POINT(6 15)')) <= 10
;
```

Although the distance is computed from closest point to closest point. Making it similar to the `ST_Intersect`. So the above example will select #2 even though it does not fit wholly inside the circle.

And yes, the second argument (0) for `GeomFromText(text,srid)`, does not play any role, you can safely ignore it. I have picked it up from some sample and it kind of stuck in my answer. I have left it out in my later edits.

btw. [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) support for spatial extension is not flawless, but it helps quite a bit to see what is in your database. Helped me with these images I have attached.

Comment: Great answer : )  To list all intersections join the table onto itself and filter away the reverse intersection: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/455a7/1/4

Comment: @StephanB Nice suggestion. Thank you. Would you mind me adding that to my answer?

Comment: Go ahead, never intended to rival your answer anyway : D

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome. Are circles also possible? That would actually be more useful in real life situations (radius type queries)

Comment: Circles are not directly supported, but if you want to do distance searching, there is a way to do it. Will edit after the hockey game is over (about 25 minutes) ;-)

Comment: Also, what is the "0" at the end of the create polygon query? Can it be ommitted?

Comment: Added info about how to work with circles. And a note underneath `Select any overlapping objects` query.