# polygon intersection with serialize data saved in db

Tags: php, mysql, arcgis

enter code hereHi currently i am following this link 
[How can I handle MySQL polygon overlap queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642159/how-can-i-handle-mysql-polygon-overlap-queries/29694610)

But my data is in serialised format saved in db.
how to make this example working for serialized data.

Currently i need to send data in this format

```
POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,0 0));
```

But my whole website data is in form

```
a:1:{i:0;a:10:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;d:174.9276744162897330170380882918834686279296875;i:1;d:-37.04082457174366282970368047244846820831298828125;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927722386324973058435716666281223297119140625;i:1;d:-37.04080921055260233742956188507378101348876953125;}i:2;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927879097423243592857033945620059967041015625;i:1;d:-37.040758815066141096394858323037624359130859375;}i:3;a:2:{i:0;d:174.9279352870431694100261665880680084228515625;i:1;d:-37.0407408936765705220750533044338226318359375;}i:4;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927883544083812239477992989122867584228515625;i:1;d:-37.04063713826327131073412601836025714874267578125;}i:5;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927876806719297064773854799568653106689453125;i:1;d:-37.04062366353426938303528004325926303863525390625;}i:6;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927792454915760345102171413600444793701171875;i:1;d:-37.04065074773956212084158323705196380615234375;}i:7;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927659728835124042234383523464202880859375;i:1;d:-37.04069332788319712790325866080820560455322265625;}i:8;a:2:{i:0;d:174.927615935965860671785776503384113311767578125;i:1;d:-37.04070747634865057307251845486462116241455078125;}i:9;a:2:{i:0;d:174.9276744162897330170380882918834686279296875;i:1;d:-37.04082457174366282970368047244846820831298828125;}}}
```

Is their any way i can make this query work

```
SELECT id,AsText(poly) FROM  `spatial` 
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(`poly`,"**MY vertices here**"))', 0 )
        )
;
```

this is my **inserting** php code, can anyone help on this task, as i m stuck from 2 weeks on this task –

```
$boundary_type='boundary'; $unstring_rings=json_decode($arguments[1]); $rings=serialize($unstring_rings); 
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix."hhq_listing_map", array('listing_id' => $arguments[0], 'location_type' => $arguments[2], 'boundary_coordinate' =>$rings, 'date_added' => date('Y-m-d') ));
```

This is my **structure** of table and i am trying to insert in boundary_coordinate coulmn, but my data coming from php in stringify form and i am decoding json and serialize it for rest of map work to save in db

```
CREATE TABLE wp_hhq_listing_map_new ( listing_map_id int(20) NOT NULL, listing_id int(20) NOT NULL, location_type varchar(255) NOT NULL, location_coordinates longtext DEFAULT NULL,boundary_coordinate geometry NOT NULL, date_added date NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How is the data serialised? You will need to write your own geometric calculation code, not easy. The whole idea of the geometry functions in mysql is to make us easy for you. Would it be possible to update your database to correctly store the data, non serialised?

Comment: You  should convert you data in proper mysql geometry data set ..

Comment: i dont know how to convert json decoded or encoded to store in db, as db only store my array in seriliaze form. how to valid data for geomtery type column

Comment: @MaartenVeerman could u please help in out in this task

Comment: I cannot give a quick help, the serialised data is hard to make any sense of. You need to figure out the structure of the serialised data, and really check the php documentation on handling JSON and inserting into databases.